# Sample python script or curl to submit ION file (xml) as MWS feed

Tags: python, curl, boto3, amazon-mws, mws

We have a use case where we want to submit an ION file (in .xml extension) to the FRPG-ops tool using MWS service. when we look into this document http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/mws.html?#boto.mws.connection.MWSConnection.submit_feed, we are not able to figure out how to submit the file as a feed. Can you able to help us with any simple solution, preferebly using boto3 or curl commands?

Thanks,
Nithya James

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes. I'm going with the approach which is used internally in Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the MWS documentation for SubmitFeed here: https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html

I'm not familiar with boto3, but the above link will show what the request should look like and an explanation of the parameters required.